# Advice for CodeIgniter views, controller and model

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my database table I have 'category_id'. All I want to do is for different categories to load different views (for example picture of cat, dog etc.).

I am getting the categories from the model with 'for' loop and I think there should be something like this

```
if($row['category'] == 'cat') $this->load->view('cat')

// this is how I get the categories

public function get_categories() {  
    $data = array();
    $q = $this->db->get('categories');
    foreach($q->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
        return $data;
}
```

But the problem is it's not a good idea to load view in the model, it has to be in the controller.
My question is what am I supposed to do, the logic to be in the model and the views for the different categories to be loaded in the controller

I hope I was clear enough and sorry for my English.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call model method from controller and return data to controller. Then in controller action you can go through result of the model method and load needed view

Comment: I have thought about this, but then I need to write the logic in the controller.  I need the write the foreach loop and if in the controller, and I don't think it is a good idea this to be in the controller

Comment: You can create additional function in model that can get array, go through it and return just view name. Then you don't need loop in controller

Answer (score 0):

Create this function in your model say "category_model"

```
public function get_categories() {  
    $q = $this->db->get('categories')->result_array();
        return $q;
}
```

Place this code in your controller

```
public function index(){
   $data=$this->category_model->get_categories();
   foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['category'] == 'cat'){
       $this->load->view('cat');
    }
}
```